# IBM Watson Assistent: Client action call to validate customer info within slot dialog node

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In a slot enabled node, I need to validate the first slot against a client database (type = Client, not cloud function or web action).

I am building a dialog to handle a phone call between an agent and a customer. in one of the beginning nodes Watson asks for customer name , date of the call and purpose of the call.

I need to capture all these in one node as user have the chance to give all information in one sentence.

Let say user will enter "I had a follow up call with John today"

Definition of 3 slots

```
 1. If recognized @sys-contact save it as $contacted_person (John) required
 2. If recognized @sys-date save it as $call_date (today) required
 3. If recognized @purpose save it as $purpose (follow up) required
```

In setup of slot 1, I have defined an action to call an external function which works perfectly, it checks the context **$contact_person** against a database and will returns a context variable named **$default_contact_person**. If the record is found then **$default_contacted_person** is equal to **$contact_person** and if there is no such name in the database the value of **$default_contact_person** will be "No Record"

I have also created a conditional response for the first slot to check the value of **$default_contact_name**

The problem is that it never reaches to the responses. It is very important that I can not split this node into two nodes because user to enter all information in one go

[image: Node setup]

[image: Configuration slot #1]

[image: Configuration slot > response 1]

```
JSON of slot 1:

{
  "context": {
    "contact_person": "@sys-person.values"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Contact_check",
      "type": "client",
      "parameters": {
        "account_name": "$contact_person"
      },
      "result_variable": "default_contact_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You defined client actions. Do the actions reach your application?

Comment: Yes it does, and as far as the application concerned, the returned value is sent back to Watson as new message. Please note I use Botkit middleware